# Цена вариативного товара в корзину

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

При помощи данного кода можно занести цену в корзину из произвольного поля. Но как только задаешь формат вывода цены на экран в контейнере `else` (**при чем исключительно для простого товара**) корзина считает и суммирует только первый разряд чисел (т.е тысячи).

Если же в контейнере `else` не задавать цене формат, все работает как часы, за исключением того что на экран выводиться неотформатированное число вместо нормальной цены **(только для простого товара!!!)**. Вариативный товар можно форматировать и вывести на экран как хочешь. **Почему?** Можно ли не переопределять цену для вывода на экран?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sv_change_product_html', 10, 2 );

function sv_change_product_html( $price_html, $product ) {

    $rrp = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'rrp_price', true );

    if ( ! empty( $rrp ) ) {
        $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( $rrp ) .'</span>';

       if($product->product_type=='variable') {

        $nrrp = number_format($rrp, 0, ',', ' ');
        $nrrp = 'от '. $nrrp;
        //$nrrp .= ' грн.';
        return $nrrp;

    } else {

        $nrrp = number_format($rrp, 0, ',', ' ');
        $nrrp .= ' грн.';
        return $nrrp;
        }
        return $rrp;
    }

}


function sv_change_product_price_cart( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $rrp = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'rrp_price', true );
    if ( ! empty( $rrp ) ) {

        $price = wc_price( $rrp );
        var_dump($price);
    }
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'sv_change_product_price_cart', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: >>корзина считает и суммирует только первый разряд чисел (т.е тысячи)<< Полистал код, воспользовался поиском, но так и не смог найти ни одного знака/оператора математического сложения. О каких суммах идёт речь? Где они?

Comment: в шаблоне **class-wc-cart.php**, туда отправляется цена
и так как в **$nrrp** отформатированное число (с разделителем тысяч) считается только первый разряд

Comment: зачем тогда вы приводите рабочий код, и молчите о том коде который не работает? ИМХО, вы должны были показать код который неправильно считает, чтобы вам подсказали как сделать этот подсчёт правильным. Сейчас по вашему вопросу я могу предложить только - убрать форматирование, потому что исходник калькулятора для нас - чёрный ящик.

Comment: в таком случае выведется неотформатированная цена товаров на экран (в магазине), можно ли отдельно вывести на экран отформатированную цену?

Comment: Так а кто мешает? Сделайте форматированние подсчитанных данных и выводите. Форматирование - это операция выполняемая, непосредственно, перед визуализацией. Логично что она не нужна на стадии подсчётов. Если у вас нет доступа к калькулятору - это уже другой вопрос.